# Fire event after fading animation complete

Tags: jquery, variables

How can I fire an event at the end of this jQuery sequence of fades?

```
$(function () {
    $('div#fds img').each(function (i) {
        $(this).delay((i++) * 1000).fadeTo(1500, 1);
    })
});
```

This fades in the img's in the #fds div from 0 to 1 over 1.5 seconds each - what I need once the last one has faded in to opacity value 1 is to change the variable END from 0 to 1.

Any ideas on how to do this? Object orientated code has never been my strong point...

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations now returns a promise, which comes in handy when waiting for multiple animations :

```
$(function(){
    var end = 0;
    $.when(
        $('div#fds img').each(function(i){
            return $(this).delay((i++)*1000).fadeTo(1500,1);
        })
    ).then(function() {
        end = 1;
    })
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nHZvW/)

Comment: Works a treat! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of fadeTo in jQuery according to the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

```
.fadeTo( duration, opacity [, complete ] )
```

complete is an optional callback function which fires after the fadeTo operation is completed.

In your code this would be:

```
$(function () {
    $('div#fds img').each(function (i) {
        $(this).delay((i++) * 1000).fadeTo(1500, 1, function() {
           // executed when done fading
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: hmm.... this fires the event after each img has faded up - not after JUST the last one... is it possible to manipulate this to work when JUST the LAST img has faded into view?

Comment: Yes, than you need to count how many images are there and how many are visible using the visible selector http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ If these numbers are equal, you expanded the last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(this).delay((i++) * 1000)
    .fadeTo(1500, 1, function(){
          $(".fire_event_class_or_id").trigger('click');  // can fire the trigger that is declared.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It combines a callback in the fadeTo method with a simple check to see if we're at the end of the function. I've changed the i++ to i+1 so it doesn't interfere with the logic in the callback (and become confusing when you come back to it):

```
$(function(){

    var len = $('div#fds img').length;

    $('div#fds img').each(function(i){
        $(this).delay((i+1)*1000).fadeTo(1500,1,function(){
            if(i == len - 1){
                END = 1;
            }
        });
    });

});
```